# Regular expressions: meaning of {2, 4}

Tags: objective-c, regex

What is the meaning of `{2,4}` when validating an email with the following regular expression:

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
```

Comment: {2,4} means words length must be between 2 & 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It mean words length is minimum 2 and maximum 4 and it takes Capital A to Z and small a to z characters..

Answer (score 1):

{2,4} means the string has minimum 2 characters and maximum 4 characters (The length of string should be greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to 4).

For example: In email ids and after dot, .com,.in, .uk so on...

Answer (score 0):

In above regular expression, {2,4} means you can take occurrence of [A-Za-z] between 2 to 4 inclusive.

Ref

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

http://www.regextester.com/